# What happens if an instance method is declared without self in python

Tags: python, oop, instance-methods

I was debugging some python code and I came across a bunch of instance methods declared without `self`. I was curious as to what happens here. Does `self` get assigned to the first variable declared here?

The code is something like shown below.

```
class myClass:
    def myFunc (var1, var2):
        return var2
```

Here is `self` assigned to `var1` ?

Comment: Why not `print var1` and find out?

Comment: @jonrsharpe : Thanks. Should have done that. Did not think of that. Printing does confirm what people have  answered here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, self (that is, the instance) will be assigned to the first variable (assuming there is no decorator like `classmethod` or `staticmethod`).

Answer (score 2):

Your code snippet is equivalent to

```
class myClass:
    def myFunc(self, var2):
        return var2
```

The first parameter is passed the instance; name is irrelevant.